# Why if a server response contain both Public: TRACE and Allow: TRACE then responds with 405 NOT allowed?

Tags: azure, curl, http-trace

**SCENARIO:**

I'm testing a web application. To test if TRACE is enabled I used both

```
nmap --script http-methods target.com
```

and

```
curl  -k -i -X OPTIONS target.com
```

After running the former I get

```
443/tcp open  https
| http-methods: 
|   Supported Methods: OPTIONS TRACE GET HEAD POST
|_  Potentially risky methods: TRACE
```

with the latter I get

```
Allow: TRACE ...
Public: TRACE ..
```

So I guess TRACE  should work. But when I run

```
curl  -k -i -X TRACE target.com
```

I get

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2
...
```

Which is not what I was expecting.

**QUESTION:**

why TRACE is blocked? is because of Azure or what?

Comment: *"is because of Azure or what?"*  - given that the response contains *"Server: Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2"* this is likely the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a false positive, according to the documentation (https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-methods.html) this script works by sending an OPTIONS:

> Finds out what options are supported by an HTTP server by sending an OPTIONS request. Lists potentially risky methods. It tests those methods **not mentioned** in the OPTIONS headers individually and sees if they are implemented. Any output other than 501/405 suggests that the method is if not in the range 400 to 600.

The methods listed in response to the OPTIONS request may not actually be supported or may be handled as a GET method. If OPTIONS request returns TRACE, nmap script does not verify this, just prints as a supported method.

You should manually verify every potentially risky method (PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, TRACE) which is returned by OPTIONS request. If response is 405 Not Allowed than method is not supported and there is no security risk.